# How to retrieve data inside a MpAndroid chart from Json array list using Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

**Here is my Json response from the sever:**

```
{
    "OpdIpdComparison": [
        {
            "Year": 2019,
            "Month": 1,
            "MonthString": "January",
            "IPD": 35,
            "OPD": 3,
            "Percent": "12.0"
        },
        {
            "Year": 2019,
            "Month": 2,
            "MonthString": "February",
            "IPD": 40,
            "OPD": 0,
            "Percent": "Infinity"
        },
        {
            "Year": 2019,
            "Month": 3,
            "MonthString": "March",
            "IPD": 53,
            "OPD": 0,
            "Percent": "Infinity"
        },
        {
            "Year": 2019,
            "Month": 4,
            "MonthString": "April",
            "IPD": 47,
            "OPD": 0,
            "Percent": "Infinity"
        }
      ]
}
```

**Here are my Model classes:**

public class OpdIpdModel {

```
@Json(name= "Year")
private Integer year;

@Json(name= "Month")
private Integer month;


@Json(name= "MonthString")
private String monthString;

@Json(name= "IPD")
private Integer iPD;

@Json(name= "OPD")
private Integer oPD;

@Json(name= "Percent")
private String percent;

public OpdIpdModel() {
}

public OpdIpdModel(Integer year, Integer month, String monthString, Integer iPD, Integer oPD, String percent) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = month;
    this.monthString = monthString;
    this.iPD = iPD;
    this.oPD = oPD;
    this.percent = percent;
}

public Integer getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(Integer year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public Integer getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public void setMonth(Integer month) {
    this.month = month;
}

public String getMonthString() {
    return monthString;
}

public void setMonthString(String monthString) {
    this.monthString = monthString;
}

public Integer getiPD() {
    return iPD;
}

public void setiPD(Integer iPD) {
    this.iPD = iPD;
}

public Integer getoPD() {
    return oPD;
}

public void setoPD(Integer oPD) {
    this.oPD = oPD;
}

public String getPercent() {
    return percent;
}

public void setPercent(String percent) {
    this.percent = percent;
}
```

}

**Api Service class:**

```
public interface ApiService {

    @GET("/Report/GetOpdIpdComparison?departmentId=473")
    Call<ModelResponse> getAllOpdIpdData();
}
```

**ModelResponse class**

```
public class ModelResponse {

    //@SerializedName("OpdIpdComparison") //for gson converter
    @Json(name = "OpdIpdComparison") //for moshi converter
    private List<OpdIpdModel> OpdIpdComparison;

    public ModelResponse(List<OpdIpdModel> opdIpdComparison) {
        OpdIpdComparison = opdIpdComparison;
    }

    public List<OpdIpdModel> getOpdIpdComparison() {
        return OpdIpdComparison;
    }

    public void setOpdIpdComparison(List<OpdIpdModel> opdIpdComparison) {
        OpdIpdComparison = opdIpdComparison;
    }
}
```

**My main class to retrieve my Jason data:**

```
    public class OpdIpdAnalysis extends AppCompatActivity{

    ApiService service;
    TokenManager tokenManager;
    Call<ModelResponse> call;

    private ListView mListView;

     //GraphView
    private BarChart mBarChart;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_opd_ipd_analysis);

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.mListView);

        //GraphView casting
        mBarChart = (BarChart)findViewById(R.id.barChart);

            //code for retrofit call

               Call<List<OpdIpdModel>> call2 = service2.getGraphData();
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<List<OpdIpdModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<OpdIpdModel>> call, Response<List<OpdIpdModel>> response) {

                if (response.body() != null){
                    List<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (OpdIpdModel opdIpdModel : response.body().getOpdIpdComparison()){

                        barEntries.add(new BarEntry(opdIpdModel.getoPD(), opdIpdModel.getiPD()));
                    }

                    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "");
                    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

                    BarData barData = new BarData();
                    barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);

                    mBarChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mBarChart.animateY(4000);
                    mBarChart.setData(barData);
                    mBarChart.setFitBars(true);

                    Description description = new Description();
                    description.setText("Growth rate per month");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<OpdIpdModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Network Status: " + t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e64a19"));
                TextView tv = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        });

}
```

> Now when i start my app it is working fine but data isn't Showing in
>   graphView. how can i solve this
>
> There is no problem in my layout.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What is the error you are getting? At which line does your app crash?

Comment: @Yserbius App is now working fine as i updated my code accrding to akshay_shahane but problem is in graphView nothing is showing, it's blank. Can't figure it out why!!

Comment: Do you still facing this problem or solve it?

Comment: Problem is solved, but still have some issues in my label on the xAxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to loop on `response.body()` which is json object not array

change it to

```
            for (OpdIpdModel opdIpdModel : response.body().getOpdIpdComparison()){
```